# Combinations of numbers arranged side by side as many as a random number (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I found the answer to my question and I want to share it.

This code is a code that creates permitting in column B based on a random number result for the numbers in column A.

```
 Option Explicit
Public Results As Object
Public MyItems As Variant

Sub CallRecur()

Dim i   As Integer, j   As Integer, rndNumb  As Integer

    j = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(3).Row
    
    ReDim MyItems(j - 1)
    
    For i = 1 To j
        MyItems(i - 1) = Cells(i, "A")
    Next i

    Set Results = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    rndNumb = 2 + 8 * Rnd
    Call Recur(UBound(MyItems), rndNumb, 0, 1, "")
    
    Range("B:B").ClearContents
    Range("B1").Resize(Results.Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Results.keys)
    Range("B:B").TextToColumns OtherChar:="|"
    
End Sub

' n is the number of items, gs is group size, d is depth,
' curix is the current index, comb is the combination so far
Sub Recur(ByRef n, ByRef gs, ByVal d, ByVal curix, ByVal comb)
Dim i As Long, comb2 As String

    For i = curix To n
        comb2 = comb & MyItems(i-1) & "|"
        If d + 1 = gs Then
            Results.Add comb2, 1
        Else
            Call Recur(n, gs, d + 1, i + 1, comb2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: I don't see how your sample code is related to your requirements..

Comment: Show us some sample data and your expected output - this might help to understand your question.

Comment: I added an excel view at the top. The combination consists of 4 numbers side by side. 251-252-253-254.
The random number will determine the number of numbers next to each other.
The random number will determine the number of columns.

Comment: Do you intend to run **once per random combinations number**?

Comment: I still cannot understand what you try doing... What you show is it **the exactly desired output**? I mean, for three columns to fill out 12 rows, for four columns 14 and for 5 to have 27 rows? Based on what logic to stop incrementation of the last two columns? Should this incrementation be extended to the other columns and you only show a part of what you need?

Comment: Hi  FaneDuru,
thank you for your interest.
In fact, the desired combinations appear in the Excel images.
Actually, I can create combinations for as many columns as I want, but I cannot make the number of columns variable.
My combination method.
Numbers increasing by 1 starting from the end.
If you have the opportunity to try the sample code I added in Excel, I will see better what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used these two websites and got the result I wanted with a small change.
https://www.excel.web.tr/threads/dinamik-sekilde-array-kullanimi.159180/
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/combinations-permutations-vba.1095593/

Option Explicit
Public Results As Object
Public MyItems As Variant

```
Sub CallRecur()

Dim i   As Integer, j   As Integer, rndNumb  As Integer

    j = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(3).Row
    
    ReDim MyItems(j - 1)
    
    For i = 1 To j
        MyItems(i - 1) = Cells(i, "A")
    Next i

    Set Results = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    rndNumb = 2 + 8 * Rnd
    Call Recur(UBound(MyItems), rndNumb, 0, 1, "")
    
    Range("B:B").ClearContents
    Range("B1").Resize(Results.Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Results.keys)
    Range("B:B").TextToColumns OtherChar:="|"
    
End Sub

' n is the number of items, gs is group size, d is depth,
' curix is the current index, comb is the combination so far
Sub Recur(ByRef n, ByRef gs, ByVal d, ByVal curix, ByVal comb)
Dim i As Long, comb2 As String

    For i = curix To n
        comb2 = comb & MyItems(i-1) & "|"
        If d + 1 = gs Then
            Results.Add comb2, 1
        Else
            Call Recur(n, gs, d + 1, i + 1, comb2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Finding a Combination of Given Number of Ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you wanted to start from 12 and build onward from there so your sample code didn't make much sense related to that. So this is what I had back then:

```
Sub randNumbersSideBySide()
    Dim rndNumb As Integer, i As Integer
    rndNumb = 2 + 8 * Rnd
    Dim arr, startNumb As Long
    ReDim arr(0 To rndNumb - 1)
    For i = 1 To rndNumb 'build first number
        startNumb = startNumb * 10 + i
    Next i
    arr(0) = startNumb
    For i = 1 To rndNumb - 1
        arr(i) = startNumb + i
    Next i
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D" & lRow + 1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        
End Sub
```

But after your further explanations, this is the newer version:

```
Sub randNumbersBasedOnOtherColumn()
    Dim rndNumb As Integer, i As Integer
    rndNumb = 2 + 8 * Rnd 'random number between 2 & 10
    Dim arr, arrAll
    ReDim arr(1 To rndNumb) 'to paste all values at once
    Dim lRowA As Long, lRowD As Long
    lRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRowD = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arrAll = Range("A1:A" & lRowA).Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = arrAll(i, 1) 'fill the array with the values from A-column
    Next i
    
    Range("D" & lRowD + 1).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

This is how it looks like on my end (and I think is what you were going for?) after letting it run 18 times:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip.
I added a new picture.
The yellow area is the area created by the macro.
I added the part that continues downwards.
the macro creates a row sorting, exactly what I want
Creating all combinations of numbers equal to the number of columns.

Comment: You wanted all of the possible combinations? Would be nice knowing this upfront :/ And what's the logic of combinations then? Will there be a "259 258 257 256 255" as a combination?

Comment: I added a new image, as it appears in Excel.
It increases by 1 starting from the end.